# CSS content and menu positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://postimg.org/image/sadzaa0up/

I'm trying to get the JS navigation buttons to fall inline with a full width background/box so the buttons aren't just floating. When I try to set this in the CSS I find the buttons aren't in line with this background/box/container. They sit slightly above it. I've tried altering margins etc but had no luck.

I'm not sure if the issue is related but I'm finding I can't position the nav bar directly beneath the logo container/header. It's being pushed so it's a 150px or so below the logo with a big gap between.

Then finally, the main body content area won't stretch to the width on the left side. I've sorted the right side using margins, yet the left side won't get rid of the gap.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

```js
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
  "<ul id='menu'>" +
  "<li><a href='Index.html'>HOME</a></li>" +
  "<li><a href='Customers.html'>SECTIONS</a></li>" +
  "<li><a href='About.html'>HOWS</a></li>" +
  "<li><a href='About.html'>OUR EXPERIENCE</a></li>" +
  "<li><a href='About.html'>TESTIMONIALS</a></li>" +
  "<li><a href='About.html'>NEWS</a></li>" +
  "<li><a href='About.html'>CONTACT US</a></li>" +
  "</ul>";

document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML =
  "<p>&copy; lumi " + new Date().getFullYear() + " All rights reserved.</p>";
```

```css
/* Check how to edit nav main background colour */

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #73008C;
  background-image: url("banner.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  content: 60px padding: 5px;
  border: 5px #73008C;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  z-index: -2;
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
#logo {
  position: center top;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
ul#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-color: #374754;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
ul#menu {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #374754;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: #374754;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  color: white;
  font-style: bold;
  background-color: #d83030;
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  background-color: #d83030;
  background-position: top center;
  margin: auto;
}
#h1 {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px ##374754;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#footer {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>LOREM IPSUM</title>
  <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div id="header"></div>

    <div id="logo">

      <img src="logo.png" alt="CROWD" style="width: 305px; height125px">

    </div>

    <nav id="nav01"></nav>

  </div>

  <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="main">

    <h1>Welcome to LOREM</h1>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque est dui, aliquam non auctor eget, maximus eu ligula. Ut sed iaculis elit, ac pharetra sem. Nam ipsum sem, consectetur id bibendum vitae, faucibus at tellus. Mauris aliquam, justo efficitur luctus vehicula, velit arcu efficitur nunc, eu volutpat diam erat ut eros. Vestibulum nec mi tristique, blandit eros sit amet, porttitor urna. Ut vehicula elit ipsum, a rhoncus erat fermentum sed. Suspendisse non diam at ex tincidunt pharetra eu id sem.</h2>

    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>more content</p>
    <p>data (more content)</p>

    <footer id="foot01"></footer>

  </div>


  <script src="Script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this question is really unclear

Comment: Sorry, new to this. Ok, well ignoring everything and just looking at the navigation. The buttons currently sit above the box the buttons should be if you follow?

So it's a horizontal navigation and instead of just having the rounded rectangle buttons floating, I want them in a box that stretches the width of the page. I can't get them to sit in a box that does this. They either sit above it or in another case when i get them to eventually line up, the box us more of just a thin line that runs behind the buttons.

Comment: As concisely as possible, what is the problem and what do you want to do?

Comment: Also, if this is a CSS question you shouldn't have javascript in it

Comment: I apologise. I basically did this to try and teach myself a bit of coding. So initially I was using the W3C site. On there they seem to use JS for the menu, I thought it should just be CSS though. I'm not sure what purpose the JS serves in it.
-
I'll add a screenshot of what I mean

Comment: You should avoid using javascript unless it is necessary

Comment: Using the chrome inspector you can copy the html generated by the javascript after it is run, take that and put in a js fiddle with the css and people can help you

Comment: I'll have a look at that now, thanks. I just added a screenshot to show it better too.

Comment: does this solve your problem? ul#menu li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

Comment: It has been fixed now, I utilised a similar method to yours and it seems fine. I'm still having trouble removing the right margine that places a gap between the nav & body box with the left of the site.

I'll keep plugging away at it. Thanks again.